# sysctl: setting key "net.ipv4.ip_forward": Invalid argument

Tags: centos, networking, kernel, kernel-modules, kvm

This is a vanilla install. I just did a yum update to Centos 7.3 and install KvM and rebooted. When following a guide and setting up IP Forwarding like I always have done I get the following:

```
sysctl: setting key "net.ipv4.ip_forward": Invalid argument
```

I tried looking up on search engines but nothing definitive as shown up yet.

Does Installing KvM change the kernel and modules in someway I don't know about?

I check /proc/net and IPv4 is not there but I see IPv6. I do have an IPv4 address in my interfaces.

Ideas?

Comment: What value are you trying to set `net.ipv4.ip_forward` to?

Comment: I was setting it to 1 to enable.

Comment: You're right, that's weird. Were you trying to change ` /etc/sysctl.conf` or running it with `/sbin/sysctl -w`? Please try the other method and tell me if there were any errors. [\[1\]](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Virtual_Server_Administration/s1-lvs-forwarding-VSA.html)

Comment: seems issue in config file, can you paste file here ?